# TXT file can be downloaded using stream on Heroku but fails for PDF files - NodeJS, Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am unable to download pdf file and view it on Heroku using **"heroku run bash"**. but same code does work for txt file on heroku. Whereas, this same code works for txt and pdf files in local machine.

I have git clone Heroku Nodejs git repository (git clone https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started.git) found here (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs) and pushed the app to the Heroku.

added fs and https libraries to nodejs project.

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
var fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.loadFromPath('./config.json');
const s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});
const URL = "<YOUR_URL>";

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

express()
  .use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
  .set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
  .set('view engine', 'ejs')
  .get('/', (req, res) => res.render('pages/index'))
  .get('/test', function(req,res) {  

    const file = fs.createWriteStream("XXXXXX-pdf.pdf");
    https.get("XXXXX-pdf.pdf", response => {
      var stream = response.pipe(file);

      stream.on("finish", function() {
        console.log("done");

        try{

            // Create params for putObject call
            const objectParams = {
                Bucket: "<YOUR_BUCKET>", 
                Key: "<YOUR_KEY>", 
                ContentLength: headers['content-length'],
                Body: stream
            };
            // Create object upload promise
            await s3.putObject(objectParams).promise();
        } catch(err){
            console.log("ERROR --->" + err)
        }
      });
    });
  })
  .listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`))
```

Comment: Exactly what happens? What do you get in the network panel? What appears in the Heroku console?

Comment: I see 'done' in heroku console. I don't get anything in network tab because I don't return any response in the backend code... so the request is open until reaches timeout.

Comment: @TomBoutell same happens for excel file and any image file ( file is not created in heroku)... other than txt file, I tried the above code with small and large files both.

Comment: Oh, I see. You got lucky with the txt file. Heroku does not have a single, persistent filesystem shared between all worker and web dynos. You must store your files in S3, or a similar cloud storage service, or a database. Any files you write to the "local drive" can only be trusted to exist on that particular dyno and will not survive a relaunch of that dyno, which could happen pretty much any time it is not in the middle of handling a request.

What is your actual goal?

Comment: @TomBoutell Yes I am aware of that, I do want to store it in S3 only and I know how to do that but before I upload it to S3. I need to download the file from external 3rd party servers... the files can reside in any domain. So, I am not quite sure if it is possible to upload the file to S3 directly from external url and so I skip downloading bit.

Answer (score 0):

"heroku run bash" does not reliably see the file that was just uploaded because there is no guarantee it is running on the same heroku dyno.

Files on heroku are temporary, they only last as long as the dyno is active and you get a limited amount of space for them too. However, you can count on them to exist in the dyno that created them long enough to finish handling a web request.

So the correct solution is to download the file, then upload it directly to a durable storage service like Amazon S3. Although the official [AWS SDK for Node.js](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/) does not provide a streaming API for uploads, this is fine because you can ask the API to upload the file you just downloaded, all before you respond to the original web request, which you must do in order to terminate it properly and avoid potential socket exhaustion in your Node.js application.

Comment: I see. so, "heroku run bash" command does not seem to be the right way to cross-verify if the files were downloaded. How can I know if a file was downloaded then? because I am having an issue with S3 upload. the files uploaded to S3 seems to be all zero bytes. so I feel like I don't have the correct path. for me to upload file successfully,  I need the the directory/folder path in which the file was downloaded... I tried few path's but no luck...

Comment: Edit your question to show code for the complete solution with s3.

Comment: Done. pls check.

Comment: The "response" object you got from https is a readable stream. You piped it to a file and waited for that to finish, and then passed the return value of pipe - a writable stream, not a readable one - to S3.

Comment: You need to just pass the response object to S3 as body. Then you are passing a readable stream where a readable stream is expected. You should pay attention when it finishes the upload because you must res.send() something or this will hang.